# Moving Row Values from one Sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I found and modified this setup.

```vb
Sub move_rows_to_another_sheet()
    '
    Sheets("User").Select
    Columns("A:Y").Select
    Range("A:Y").Activate
    '
    For Each myCell In Selection.Columns(25).Cells
        If myCell.Value = "Closed" Then
            myCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
            myCell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next
    '
    Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

Updated Version - Move Single Rows

```vb
''Updated Version - Move Single Rows
'
Sub move_rows_to_another_sheet()
    '
    Sheets("Users").Select
    Columns("A:Y").Select
    Range("A:Y").Activate
    '
    For Each mycell In Selection.Columns(25).Cells
    '
    If mycell.Value = "Closed" Then
        mycell.EntireRow.Copy
        Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        mycell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Next
    '
Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

The current code is successful, however, I would like to paste the values of the rows cell content and not the formulas etc. I just need the result of the functioning formulas recorded.

I tried options such as `myCell.EntireRow.CopyValues` & even `Rows.Count & Rows.PasteSpecial`.

Comment: mycell.EntireRow.Copy
Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Compile error - End of statement.  It halts on, Select [Selection] . PasteSpecial?

Comment: Did you start a new line after the `.Select`?

Comment: No @GSerg.. I'll give it another go though, I would like to see the suggestion work.

Comment: Tried the change. [Selection] on new line and not. When on a new line, it flags up an issue with ".End(xlUp).Select"

Comment: Found this to work with. "...End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=PasteValue".  While it works, the process has become a little clunky!  Any suggestions are still welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code. It looks like when there are several cells with "closed" it will not work for all. because when one deletes, one should delete from below upwards.
But then the data in Archive is not in right order.

In your original code you can make the range smaller, so it will run faster.

or take what you want from this code:

```
 Sub move_rows_to_another_sheet2()

    
    Dim mycell As Range
    Dim checkClosed
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    
    Set checkClosed = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("User").Range("Y1:Y10000")
    Lastrow = Worksheets("Archive").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'one cell below last used cell in column A

    For i = 10000 To 1 Step -1 'from row 10000 to row 1
        Set mycell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("User").Cells(i, "Y")
        
        If LCase(mycell.Value) = "closed" Then 'checks for Closed and closed
            mycell.EntireRow.Copy
            Worksheets("Archive").Range("A" & Lastrow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            mycell.EntireRow.Delete
            Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
        End If
    Next i
    '
    Range("A2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Both VBA models now work with my inlaid specs... however, this one is definitely a lot less clunky.  Much appreciated @weareone

Comment: It also works with multiple (different) rows with the same criteria and pastes them in order within the archive page, it then also deletes the multiple moved rows.

Comment: @ShadowCrown when copy it, last row with closed tag will appear first in the archive, oposide order. But one could change that. Making 2 loops. One for copy and paste, the other for deleting.

Comment: appreciated.  When exploring the impact of the process, it is sound enough, as the rows use unique IDs and the Archive, if the need arises, is also filtered to organise criteria.  I am searching and playing with advancing the code to identify more than one row/column, with Closed, and or Passed, and or Failed.  It'll get there :)

Comment: @ShadowCrown Hint: read about option explecid in top of VBA Modul. Apply it. For each column you need to add a new variable like mycell. Name doesn't matter. One line for declaring the variable (Dim) and one line to define the range. i is the row counter, "y" is the column. Then Google how to do an if and or statement. Be careful to apply right parenthesis. Add first one condition, make it work, then add one more condition. If you need more help make a new question. I will be offline for very long time.